# how to get span items after < !--- > in soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

Hi I am trying to get the item `377` after the sold where it is followed by a   `< !-- -- >`. How do i do so?I got 2 items with the following code. I added space so that it's visible.

```
sold = soup.find_all('span', {"class":"jsx-302 jsx-385"})
```

Result:

```
<span class=""jsx-302 jsx-385""><span class=""jsx-302 jsx-385 sold-text"">Sold</span> < !-- -- >377</span>, 

<span class=""jsx-302 jsx-385"">Rp41,400 / 100 g</span>
```

I can do a regex to get only the first `items[0].text` containing  sold and ignore the rest. However is there a way to handle span with `< !-- -- >` that is in brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would agree to use `split()` but `HTML` look not that valid, so behavior of `< !-- -- >` or `<!-- -->` is not clear.

In case of `< !-- -- >`:

```
soup.select_one('span:has(.sold-text)').text.split('>')[-1]
```

In case of `<!-- -->`:

```
soup.select_one('span:has(.sold-text)').text.split(' ')[-1]
```

I would recommend to `filter` for digits:

```
''.join(filter(str.isdigit, soup.select_one('span:has(.sold-text)').text))
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Comment

html = '''
<span class="jsx-302 jsx-38""><span class="jsx-302 jsx-385 sold-text">Sold</span> < !-- -- >377</span>
<span class="jsx-302 jsx-385">Rp41,400 / 100 g</span>
'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

sold = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, soup.select_one('span:has(.sold-text)').text))

print(sold)
```

###### Output

```
377
```